# PostGIS Dissolve/Union close polygons

Tags: postgis, dissolve, union

I have approximately 1 million polygons that have been split by lines. However, this has caused one half of a polygon to be separated by approximately 50cm from its other half.

After doing a lot of attempts using a variety of methods I still have not come up with a reliable solution.

I would like to end up with individual features which have had the closest polygons merged together to create one feature. It probably needs to be based on a tolerance or buffer.

1) Using Union and SnapToGrid as explained by Paul Ramsey in another question
([Joining lots of small polygons to form larger polygon using PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31895/what-is-the-best-way-to-join-lots-of-small-polygons-to-form-a-larger-polygon))

```
 CREATE TABLE merged AS
 SELECT ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(the_geom,0.0001)) 
 FROM parishes
 GROUP BY county_name;
```

This did a great job of doing a union on the parts of each polygon, however, I was left with just one feature. So my 1 million polygons and been merged into a MultiPart. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

2) Using Topology
I then wondered if I might be able to use topology within PostGIS 2.0. I found this very difficult to implement as there are very few examples.

```
 -- Create a topology
SELECT CreateTopology('new_topology', 27700, 'geom'));

-- Add a layer
SELECT AddTopoGeometryColumn('new_topology', 'public', 'original_polygons', 'topogeom', 'MULTIPOLYGON');
```

This creates the edges and faces but how should I now use this to create a new polygon layer?

3) ST_Snap - it seems this will snap a geometry to another geometry. I could not get this to work as I was trying to snap to the same geometry. This may work though as I could snap the points on one side of the polygon to its matching set and then dissolve.

Are there any other options or advice on how to achieve what I am after?

Comment: Would it be too bad if you pass polygons by St_buffer(the_geom, 0.5), St_Union the result and the use again St_Buffer but with -0.5? The polygons should dissolve correctly but it's boundaries won't be exactly the same as before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should use [ST_Dump](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) to disaggregate your Multi-part polygon created in your step (1):

```
SELECT ST_Dump( 
   ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(the_geom,0.0001))
   FROM parishes
   GROUP BY county_name
);
```

Comment: I believe that the problem is that, due to the small gaps (50 cm) between polygons, the st_union is unable to dissolve the boundaries, and St_Dump will revert the problematic polygons back to it's initial state.

Comment: thanks Alexandre and mtn.biker, I tried both and the ST_Dump ends up doing what I needed, however I only got it working when i did this CREATE TABLE merged_dump AS
 SELECT  
 (ST_Dump(ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(wkb_geometry,0.09)))).geom as geom 
 FROM buildings;