# Merge adjacent polygons and return all (adjacent and not adjacent) as Multipolygon?

Tags: postgresql, polygon, geojson, merge

I have a postgres database with administrative boundaries and their geometry.
Each of those boundaries have an ident number.

What I want to achieve:

First I want to select all rows which are starting with a particular zip code.
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM "post" WHERE "post"."ident" LIKE '101%'
```

All of those Geometries which are adjacent should be merged and those which are not should also be returned.

I have tried those statements:

This one I have from this answer:

[Joining lots of small polygons to form larger polygon using PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31895/what-is-the-best-way-to-join-lots-of-small-polygons-to-form-a-larger-polygon)

```
with t as (
select (st_dump(geom)).geom 
from "post"
where "post"."ident" LIKE '593%'
) select ST_UNION(geom) from t;
```

But this statement returns only those polygons which are adjacent but others are not included

```
with t as (
select (st_dump(geom)).geom 
from "post"
where "post"."ident" LIKE '593%'
) select ((ST_Dump(ST_UNION(geom)))) from t;
```

I get 2 rows, and it seems that this could be what I want, but I cannot get the result als ST_AsText.

Is there a statement which returns all polygons merged where necessary and return it ideally as geoJSON or maybe as text?

Answer (score 2):

OP's answer:

```
with t as (
select (st_dump(geom)).geom 
from "post"
where "post"."ident" LIKE '593%'
) select ST_AsGeoJSON((ST_Dump(ST_UNION(geom))).geom) from t;
```

So you can access geometries and transform it into geoJSON. Adjacent geometries are merged and you get all other geometries which are also not included in merged polygon.