# What is the best way to merge lots of small adjacents polygons ? (POSTGIS)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, merge

I am looking for a way to merge lots of small adjacents polygons.

I have this kind of features:

[image: polygon_to_merge]

So if my polygons are adjacents AND have the same color attribute then I want to merge those polygons. Typically I want to merge the selected features of the picture. I try to add a "ST_TOUCHES" condition but all the polygons are not necessarily connected to each other.

Another [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31895/what-is-the-best-way-to-join-lots-of-small-polygons-to-form-a-larger-polygon) on this website is similar to this one but don't take into account that polygons need to be connected.

So the first step should be something like:

```
 SELECT ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(the_geom,0.0001)) 
 FROM my_poly
 GROUP BY color;
```

But how to add the "need to be connected" condition ?

Any ideas ?

**EDIT**

I found a solution:

Step 1) Merge all the polygons that have the same color.

Step 2) Split multiparts polygons to singleparts polygons.

```
SELECT (ST_DUMP(ST_UNION(ST_SNAPTOGRID(the_geom,0.0001)))).geom, color
FROM my_poly
GROUP BY color
```

But there is perhaps a better solution, because i'm loosing some informations during the step 1).

Comment: What is bugging me is the cost of ST_Union for all polygons just to break it in parts again. Would maybe a ST_Union to a subset be faster and more efficient, let's say only to features inside a certain buffer/nearest neighbour or similar?

Comment: @bennos Actually the query take ~1.5 seconds for 2500 polygons. So it's not that bad. And the idea of adding a buffer is a little bit dangerous !

Comment: ST_ClusterWithin does exactly that: merges features based on a distance threshold. However, I don't see anything particularly wrong with what you already have.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @obchardon I am working with a large datasets where ST_Union takes hours, thus your question is of specific interest for me. Breaking the dataset into smaller chunks is one way I was doing my research on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

**Step 1)** Merge all the polygons that have the same attribute 'color'.

**Step 2)** Split multiparts polygons to singleparts polygons with ST_DUMP.

```
SELECT (ST_DUMP(ST_UNION(ST_SNAPTOGRID(the_geom,0.0001)))).geom, color
FROM my_poly
GROUP BY color
```

But there is perhaps a better solution, because i'm loosing some informations during the step 1).

ST_Dump returns a geometry (geom) and an array of integers (path). So to select only the geometry you have to write `(ST_Dump(my_geometry)).geom`