# Single-ringed GeoJSON polygon in Mongodb

Tags: polygon, mongodb

I've loaded the Census' zip code data into a mongo database.

I can query specific zip codes like this:

`db.zips.findOne({"properties.ZCTA5CE10":"80205"})`
`db.zips.findOne({"properties.ZCTA5CE10":{$in:["80205", "80202"]}})`

For the second mongo find, this is what those zip codes would look like on a map:
[image: Zip Codes]

Now I want to query specific zip codes and "merge" any that are tangent creating single polygons.  For example, in the second example I want to draw those two polygons as a single polygon.

Is there a way to do that with mongodb?

In postgis I think I could accomplish this with ST_Collect or ST_Union [(related stack overflow question)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31895/what-is-the-best-way-to-join-lots-of-small-polygons-to-form-a-larger-polygon).